# hide graph based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel VBA, and I am trying to solve this problem with VBA code.

Basically, my sheet has 12 charts and 12 tables. At any given time, only one table will get data and only that graph should be seen. The other 11 graphs should be hidden.

I have tried this

```
Sub getchart()

    If Range("C1") = Vub Then
      ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_33").Visible = True
    Else
      ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_33").Visible = False
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can take this macro and assign it to a command button you add somewhere on your sheet. The problem is there's nothing triggering it to run. See Mr ML's answer below for another method that uses the `Worksheet_change` event. Just keep in mind that event will run any time you make a change to the sheet. If you have a lot of data or changes, it could slow it down.

Comment: will this code hide the graph? or will it be still visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the graph to change from visible to not visible as you change the value of the cell you need to use an event.

e.g.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$C$1" Then
  if target.value = "vub" then
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_33").Visible = True
  Else
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_33").Visible = False
  end if
End If

End Sub
```

This code should be inserted in the *sheet module* for the sheet in which your graph is placed. The sheet module can be found in the sidebar.

Comment: I guess, second `Visible` must be `False`

Comment: side bar as in right clicking on the sheet on which the vba code needs to be run on and then view code and then paste the above code right?

Answer (score 1):

You can cut down @MrML's answer to:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$C$1" Then
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_33").Visible = (target = "vub")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @jijoythomas It means that this chart doesn't exists (i.e. with such name).

Comment: yes, I solved that... but when I run it, a window appears asking me to save the code and then run it what name should I enter?

Comment: please check the image @johnyl

Comment: @jijoythomas Read carefully - I substituted the *body* of procedure in MrML's answer. This code must be in `Worksheet_Change`.

Comment: but when i paste that it opens up a window and ask's me to save the code first... and when i type a name... it opens another tab ..what should i do?

Comment: @jijoythomas So, save it! 

Comment: when i am saving it ...it opens a new sub :(

Comment: check the image i added to the description @johnyl

Comment: @jijoythomas Aha! The procedure must be in sheet's module, but now it's in standard module!

Comment: How do I add it to the sheet's module?