# Hide Excel Graph based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, graph

I dont know VBA and i am looking for some support. I want the graph to be visible based on some condition.

If A2 = 0 so dont show any graph
If A2 > 0 then Show Graph1

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71618735/4961700

Comment: Check this on searching Google the first link it gave was from `StackOverflow` **[Hide Graph Based On Cell Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53864739/hide-graph-based-on-cell-value)**